# Please explain the definition of Feisty

Tags: meaning, word-usage, historical-change

I thought I knew the correct definition but now I was told I'm using it wrong. I was trying to describe a certain (rescue) dogs personality to someone and I said that he can be a bit feisty when playing and when getting him out of the kennel and at times will snap and try to bite. What I was meaning is that he can be a bit nervous and a little snippy sometimes and gets wound up a bit but isn't an all out vicious dog. Just some occasional aggression here and there. Otherwise is playful and happy. This person said I'm using the word wrong. That feisty means happy, excitable, mischievous playful, spirited. Like it's a positive, not a negative. I honestly thought it could be both depending on the context. Can it be both? Is one more correct than the other?

Have I been using the word wrong this whole time???

Comment: No, it's fine. You are probably hanging out with the wrong people.

Answer (score 3):

***Tracking 'feist' and 'feisty' in Merriam-Webster dictionaries***

*Feisty* has an interesting record in English, to judge from the entries for it and for its root word *feist* in various editions of Merriam-Webster dictionaries. To start with, its etymology is odd, as we see in this entry for *feist* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **feist** *n* {obs. *fisting hound*, fr. obs. *fist* to break wind} (1770) *chiefly dial* : a small dog

Here is the corresponding entry for the adjective *feisty* in the *Eleventh Collegiate*:

> **feisty** *adj* **feistier**, **-est** (1896) **1** *chiefly Southern & Midland* **a :** full of nervous energy : FIDGETY **b :** TOUCHY, QUARRELSOME **c :** exuberantly frisky **2 :** having or showing a lively aggressiveness : SPUNKY {the movie's feisty heroine}

From this record, we might conclude that *feist* as a little dog has been an English word since at least 1770, that *feisty* emerged from the noun by 1896, and that the adjective form—after initially meaning "fidgety"—subsequently expanded to include first the meaning "touchy or quarrelsome" and then the meaning "spunky."

Now let's see how Merriam-Webster dictionaries through the years have actually handled *feist* and *feisty*. The first surprise is that neither word (nor any variant word) appears in a Merriam-Webster dictionary until *Webster's International Dictionary* (1890), which has this brief entry for *fice*:

> **Fice** *n.* A small dog ; — written also *fise*, *fyce*, *fiste*, etc. {*Southern U.S.*}

The next full-size Merriam-Webster dictionary, *Webster's New International Dictionary* (1909), drops its predecessor's entry for *fice*, but for the first time offers entries for *feist* and for *fist* in the relevant sense:

> **feist** *n.* {Prop[erly] a *fisting dog*, from dial. or obs. *fist* to break wind, fr. (assumed) A[nglo-]S[axon]. *fīstan*.} A small dog. Same as FIST, *n.*, 3. *Local, U.S.*
>
> ...
>
> **fist** *n.* {see FEIST} **1.** A breaking wind ; a foul odor. *Obs.* **2.** A puffball. *Obs.* except in bull*fist*, puck*fist*, etc. **3.** A small dog (not designating any breed) ; — also called *fice*, *fyste*, etc. Often applied in contempt to man.

Next comes *Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, third edition (1916), which again shuffles entries and definitions to make *fice* the primary relevant entry and adds a new twist to the definition:

> **feist** *n.* A fice. *U. S.*
>
> ...
>
> **fice** *n.*, or **fice dog**. {Prop[erly] a *fisting dog*, from dial. or obs. *fist* to break wind} A small, worthless dog, a cur. *U. S.*
>
> ...
>
> **fist** *n.* A fice. *U. S.*

The fourth edition of *Webster's Collegiate* (1931) repeats the entries for all three words (*feist*, *fice*, and *fist*) verbatim, but the ground shifts again in the fifth edition (1936), which unceremoniously drops all three entries. In the sixth edition (1949), all three words are back in place, along with two new variant, *feice* and *fyce*—and at long last, they bring *feisty* (and *ficety* and *fisty*) with them:

> **feice**. Var. of FEIST.
>
> **feist** *n.* Also **feice**, **fice**, **fist**, **fyce**. *Local, U. S.* A small dog.
>
> **feisty** *adj.* Also **ficety**, **fisty**. *Local U. S.*  Variously: frisky, meddlesome, pesky, cocky, touchy, or spunky.
>
> ...
>
> **fice**, **ficety**. Vars. of FEIST, FEISTY.
>
> ...
>
> **fist**. Var. of FEIST.
>
> ...
>
> **fisty**. Var. of FEISTY.
>
> ...
>
> **fyce**, n. Var. of FEIST.

That's quite a steamer trunk to unpack, but two things jump out at you right away. First, the multitude of separate entries in the dictionary for variant spellings suggests an unusually fluid situation with regard to orthography; a dictionary normally doesn't list five different ways to spell the same noun in five different places in the dictionary. This provides strong circumstantial evidence that, even in 1949, *feist* and *feisty* were not well established as "the right way" to spell the two words. Second, the definition for *feisty* already contains—in scattershot style—three of the four meanings that the *Eleventh Collegiate* reports—all but the one that the *Eleventh Collegiate* claims came first ("fidgety").

The *Seventh Collegiate* (1963) winnows the offerings a bit, removing the entries for *feice*, *ficety*, *fist*, and *fisty*, but retaining the brief "variant" entries for *fice* and *fyce*. The entry for *feist* in the *Seventh Collegiate* is identical to the one that appears forty years later in the *Eleventh Collegiate* (except that Merriam-Webster started noting words' first occurrence dates starting in the *Ninth Collegiate* [1983]). But the entry for *feisty* is considerably more orderly in the *Seventh Collegiate* than it was in it predecessor:

> **feisty** *adj. chiefly South & Midland* : being in a state of excitement or agitation: as  **a :** full of nervous energy : FIDGETY **b :** touchy and quarrelsome **c :** frisky and exuberant.

This contrasts with the sixth edition's omission of the "fidgety" meaning and with its inclusion of the "spunky" meaning. The *Eighth Collegiate* (1973) leaves the entries unchanged, except that it adds a quotation from E.E. Rebstock that demonstrates (not entirely helpfully) the use of *feisty* in the wild: "found us irritated, upset, *feisty*." The *Ninth Collegiate* (1983) brings the entries entirely up to date, adding the first recorded occurrence dates of 1770 for *feist* and 1896 for *feisty*, and the "having or showing a lively aggressiveness : SPUNKY" definition to the entry for *feisty*.

---

***Another angle on 'feisty'***

The "breaking wind" sense of *fist*—mentioned in Merriam-Webster's etymological note on *feist*—receives considerable attention in J.S. Farmer & W.E. Henley, *Slang and Its Analogues Past and Present*, volume 3 (1893) in an entry for *foist*:

> **FOIST**, **FOYST**, or **FYST**, *subs.* (old). ... **3.** (old).—A silent emission of wind through the anus(see quot., sense 2); a CHEESER. *See* FART and FOUSTY. {Coles has to *fyst*, vissio; which in his Latin part he renders to *fizzle*. Also FYSTING CUR; and in Sherwood's English Dictionary, subjoined to Cotgrave, FYSTING CURS, and others of the same class, are fully illustrated.}
>
> [First four cited instances:] **1598.** FLORIO, *A Worlde of Wordes*. *Loffa*, a fizle, a fiste, a close farte. **1605** JONSON, *Eastward Hoe*, pl. iv., 270. Marry, fyst o' your Ruidess. I thought as much. **1662** *Rump Songs*, II., . That a reason be enacted (if there be not one), Why a fart hath a voice, and a fyst hath none, Which nobody can deny. **1690** B. E., *Dict. of the Canting Crew*. **Foyst** ... also a close strong stink, without noise or report.

This adds an element of unpleasantness to the idea of "foisting" something on someone. It also strongly suggests that a "fisting cur" refers specifically to a dog that noiselessly farts.

Mitford Mathews, *A Dictionary of Americanisms on Historical Principles* (1951) notes the connection to foist in his entry for *feist*:

> **feist,** *n.* Also **fice, fist.** Chiefly *S[outhern]* ... A small dog, sometimes wioth a derogatory implication. Cf in *OED fysting curre* (1529), *fisting hound* (1576), *foisting hound* (1611), *fisting dog* (1688), etc. [First four cited instances:] **1770** Washington *Diaries* I. 371 A small foist looking yellow cur. **1805** Dow *Journal* (1814) 265 Bob Sample, one of the most popular A-double-L-part {predestinarian} preachers in the country, ... like a little fice (or cur dog) would rail behind my back. **1850** Garrard *Wah-To-Yah* iv, 60 In our lodge were three huge curs and four cross feists. **1917** Mathewson *Sec. Base Sloan* 34 In Missouri or Mississippi he would have been labeled 'fice,' which is equivalent to saying that he was a terrier-like dog of no particular breed.

Mathews's entry for feisty is also interesting:

> **feisty,** *a.* {f[rom] prec[eding—that is, *feist*]} Fidgety, belligerent. *Colloq.* **1913** Kephart, *So. Highlanders* 94 Feisty means when a feller's allers wigglin' about, wantin' ever'body to see him, like a kid when the preacher comes. **1926** Roberts *Time of Man* 152 That there feisty bay mare jumped straight upwards and broke the tongue outen the plow. **1947** *Sat[urday] Review* 27 Sep. 12/3 It signifies nothing, and is washed away in mirth and song, dust of road, clamor of county fair, folk-talk unspoiled with learning, part Bible, part Elizabethan, 'feisty and fractious' as Samantha says.

---

***Conclusions***

Despite not receiving formal attention of Merriam-Webster until surprisingly recently (1949), *feisty* has a colorful (and pungent) past.Although *fysting curre* dates back to at least 1529 in England, the sources I consulted seem to agree that *feisty* emerged first in U.S. English usage, as a product of one of those old words generally lost from old country usage but preserved in one or more pockets of the colonies.

Once we get to the figurative meanings of "like a small, spirited  dog," the possible meanings of the word diverge markedly. On the one hand, *feisty* can have a quite positive sense: frisky, spirited, exuberant, spunky. On the other, it can tend toward negative characteristics: fidgety, touchy, or quarrelsome. This split in meanings is (it seems to me) true to the mixed nature of the canine from which it is derived, whether or not that animal has the additional habit of passing gas.

Answer (score 2):

**feisty** (adj.) [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/feisty)

1896, "aggressive, exuberant, **touchy**," American English, with -y (2) + feist "small dog," earlier fice, fist (American English, 1805); short for **fysting curre** "stinking cur," attested from 1520s

And  [cuteness.com](https://www.cuteness.com/blog/content/are-smaller-dogs-more-feisty-than-big-dogs):

> In modern use, feisty typically refers to dogs who are reactive,
>   confident and have a little bit of attitude [sic!].

You and your friend are both correct.  One man's dog is another's 'curre'!

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! It has helped tremendously. :-D